# Bug with CupertinoIcons.create and .square_pencil?

Tags: flutter

In the description of both `CupertinoIcons.create`, and `CupertinoIcons.square_pencil` it says 'Not filled in'.

But for me both in their reference websites as well as in the app, create looks identical to `create_solid`, same with `square_pencil` and `square_pencil_fill` .

It seems they are missing the version which is not filled.

Is there a fix for this?

I expected there to be a difference between .create and .`create_solid`, and .`square_pencil` and .`square_pencil_fill`. But there wasn't.

```
Icon(CupertinoIcons.square_pencil, size: 34)
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82634

It is an active issue. You can use an SVG or Other Icons or add a custom icon.

Comment: Thanks Krish Bhanushali,

looking at that post it seems, that this problem is already known for more than 3 years. so the way is to find another icon, or adding svg.
thanks